# React Native, iOS build fails with react-native-maps [RESOLVED]

Tags: ios, react-native, google-maps

I hope someone here could help me with my issue.

I'm using react-native v 0.73.2

On android the application successfully builds but I have issue with building the iOS version.
Cocopods have been successfully installed, but when running "yarn ios" I am struck with this error:

```
The following build commands failed:
    CompileC /Users/nino/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PlitviceMobile-aonymzxbkvahywhidgtjlsmxrplx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PlitviceMobile.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PlitviceMobile.build/Objects-normal/arm64/AIRGoogleMapOverlayManager.o /Users/nino/code/plitvice/node_modules/react-native-maps/ios/AirGoogleMaps/AIRGoogleMapOverlayManager.m normal arm64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'PlitviceMobile' from project 'PlitviceMobile')
(1 failure)
```

when running it from xcode I have got this stack of errors.

[image: first error]
[image: second error]

Anyone has any ideas what might be the issue and how could I resolve this?

I have already tried running everything that I have found online including:

- reinstalling react-native-maps
- reinstalled pods
- cleaned the build folder
- ran the build from xcode

Comment: Instead of sharing screenshots add error as plain text.

Comment: Does [this](https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/issues/2573#issuecomment-436383201) helps you in solving your issue?

Comment: @RohitAggarwal thanks for the comment, I have tried that one but does not help my case unfortunately. :/

Comment: Can you try providing a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates this issue that we can try?

Comment: @Yrll thanks, when I was trying to do that I managed to resolve the issue. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whoever stumbles upon this particular issue I hope this will help.
I have managed to resolve it for my case.
I was upgrading from version <0.60 to latest 0.73 version and the application had some registered sources in the Target > Compile sources.

Most of it was concerning google dependencies of react-native-maps like AIRGoogleManager and similar.

I have deleted them all and just left main.m and AppDelegate.mm, after which I was able to build the project.

Steps before that were:

- add HAVE_GOOGLE_MAPS=1 to targets > Build settings > Preprocessor macros
- add this to Build settings > Header Search Paths -> ${SRCROOT}/../node_modules/react-native-maps/ios/AirMaps and make it recursive from non-recursive
- upgraded cocoapod installer
- upgraded xcodeproj
- in build settings I have excluded unneeded architectures.
- in project -> build settings -> No Common Block: YES
- all versions of iOS I have set to reflect the one in my podfile (13.4)
- I have disabled flipper kit by commenting this line in podfile:

```
# Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
# you should disable the next line.
#    :flipper_configuration => flipper_config,
```

I hope this helps someone.